# Javascript onchange checkbox cancel

Tags: javascript, html, events, checkbox, onchange

My first question here and really hope to learn a lot. I'm actually not the technical guy at my startup but cause of the lack of it trying to do things by myself :-)

I made an onchange event for my module order system. When i click on the checkbox, the selected module appears in the summary. This works. But when i deselect the checkbox, i want the module to dissapear from the summary. That doesn't work now. What do i have to change in the JS to do that?

**The checkbox**

```
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" 
  onchange="modulecontractsSelect(this, event)">
```

**The summary**

```
<p id="module-contracts-summary"> </p>
<p id="module-contracts-summary-price"> </p>
```

**The Javascript**

```
function modulecontractsSelect() {
    document.getElementById("module-contracts-summary").innerHTML = "Module contractbeheer"
    document.getElementById("module-contracts-summary-price").innerHTML = "€5 / mnd";
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: because Your function doesn't know at all is checkbox checked or not, and at 1st place your function even don't know nothing about checkbox, you doesn't set. btw. I really think You don't need `event`, only `this`... there is fiddle example https://jsfiddle.net/hej11u6g/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, change your `checkbox`'s `onchange` event to pass only itlsef (as `this`) as a parameter. You don't really need to pass the event as a parameter:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" onchange="modulecontractsSelect(this);">
```

Then, change your `modulecontractsSelect` function to receive the checkbox (`this`) as a parameter (I highlighted it for you with an arrow below). If the checkbox is `checked`, set the `innerHTML` values. If it's not `checked`, set them to an empty string:

```
                                   ▼
function modulecontractsSelect(checkbox) {
    if (checkbox.checked) {
       document.getElementById("module-contracts-summary").innerHTML = "Module contractbeheer"
       document.getElementById("module-contracts-summary-price").innerHTML = "€5 / mnd";
    }
    else {
       document.getElementById("module-contracts-summary").innerHTML  = "";
       document.getElementById("module-contracts-summary-price").innerHTML  = "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your checkbox code to something like:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" onchange="modulecontractsSelect(this.checked)">
```

Then change your `modulecontractsSelect` function to something like:

```
function modulecontractsSelect(is_checked) {
    if( is_checked ) {
        document.getElementById("module-contracts-summary").innerHTML = "Module contractbeheer"
        document.getElementById("module-contracts-summary-price").innerHTML = "€5 / mnd";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("module-contracts-summary").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("module-contracts-summary-price").innerHTML = "";
    }
}
```

Please note I haven't tested this code, but you should get the idea.

Comment: Only down voting shows how irresponsible the world is, explanation please. Particularly considering the fact that the answer above mine was edited to match my answer.

Comment: Not only I did not downvote your answer, I am upvoting it myself.

Comment: I didn't down vote but, well, maybe because **Please note I haven't tested this code**, and someone already answered in comment long time ago.

Comment: Both the answers were posted in about the same time frame, mine was late by may be a minute or so. But thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)